# How to write an if statement involving the combination of dates and other measures in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm newbie in Tableau and I'm struggling to come up with a formula that would show me a number of service tickets that were in the "on hold" state (at some point) before they were set to "in progress".

States of a ticket include new, on hold, in progress, resolved.

Basically what I want is:

Show me the count of only those tickets that were in the "on hold" state, which preceeded "in progress" state.

Normally, the lifecycle of a ticket follows the order of states mentioned above. However, there are some abnormalities I'm trying to identify with data.

I have timestamps for when each state started but I don't really know what to do with them.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share sample data so we can see how it's structured?

Comment: Without having a look on your data structure, it is very difficult to comprehend your problem.